# How to add node to list of clients that can access a data bag on a Chef Server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, knife, databags, chef-vault

I want/need one of my nodes to access a data bag on my chef server. The purpose is to get a decrypted ssh key so i can clone from a private repo. I've been trying many variations of

```
knife vault update data_bag item -A 'name-of-node'
```

But I do not see the node come up on the list of clients with access.

What am I doing wrong in this command or need to do to get this to work? I've been following this [guide](http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2013/09/10/managing-secrets-with-chef-vault/), but I'm not using roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that this command works for updating, but it basically adds all nodes and users. Would prefer a more precise answer for just an individual node if someone has one.

```
knife vault update data_bag item --search '*:*' --admins me --mode client
```

https://github.com/chef/chef-vault/issues/181

https://github.com/chef/chef-vault/blob/master/THEORY.md

EDIT:

As the user in the comments mentioned, this too works and is more correct.

knife vault create data_bag item '{"itemname":"securepass"}' --search 'name:my-node-name' --admins me --mode client

Comment: Try a search that zeros in on your server. --search "name:myservername"

Comment: I will try that later when i have time and leave a comment.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor That did work, i had thought i'd tried that but I must have used 'node' instead of 'name'. I thought the chef documents said you could pass 'role','node', and some other option, but not name.